# Convert form input fields of an HTML table to JSON

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-table, innerhtml

I'm currently learning javascript and as an exercice I'm trying to convert an HTML form table to JSON, send it over a communication interface and adding it to another page.

I'm currently able to parse the content of most fields by running through the table with the following code.

```
function tableToJson(table)
{
    var data = [];

    var headers = [];
    for(var i=0; i<table.rows[0].cells.length; i++)
    {
        headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
    }

    for(var i=1; i<table.rows.length; i++)
    {
        var tableRow = table.rows[i];
        var rowData = {};

        for(var j=0; j<tableRow.cells.length; j++)
        {
            rowData[ headers[j] ] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
        data.push(rowData);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(data);
}

var tables = document.getElementsByTagName("table");

if(tables.length > 0)
{
    var json = tableToJson(tables[0]);
    console.log(json);
    /* Send part bellow */
}
```

I'm also able to send it through communication once it has been converted and to reimplement it into a new popup from the received JSON.

The problem I'm facing is when some of the fields are input tags with pre-filled values as follow.

```
<td style="width: 8%; vertical-align: middle; border-top: 1px solid rgba(56, 103, 214, 0.2);">
    <input type="number" step="0.01" name="form[18046][amount]" class="form-control">
</td>
```

The value is not directly available into the cell's innerHTML so the converted JSON data contains the HTML code but not the pre-filled value so when I reimplement the table on the new popup, I have an empty input field.

I would like to be able to get the prefilled value from the innerHTML so I can get rid of the input tag to keep only the value.

Maybe the best way would be to access the value `form[18046][amount]` through the DOM  but I can't find a way to do it.

Does somebody knows how I could get the input prefilled value instead of the cell's innerHTML ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to get the pre-filled value by parsing the innerHTML string to retrieve the 'name' attribute value and to ask the DOM the associated value.

```
var name = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML.replace(/.*name="([^"]+)".*$/g, "$1");
rowData[headers[j]] = document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value;
```

I'm still oppened to any other solution, I feel like this ain't the best one at all.